# AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Tags: apache, localhost, pid

I've tried to run apache server with

```
sudo apachectl start
sudo apachectl stop
```

and I encountered these errors

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using exampleui-MacBookPro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   (48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8080
>   (48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs
>   AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Hoonui-MacBookPro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   httpd (pid 6276?) not running

So I searched stackoverflow and exchanged `ServerName localhost` in `etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file to `ServerName localhost:8080` and it was uncommented already.

It didn't change even after changing ServerName into

localhost
localhost:80
localhost:8080
127.0.0.1

and I also tried to kill process with `kill -9 pid` but nothing changed

Comment: Please post your httpd.conf file here. The error "could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080" and "[::]:8080" indicate that some service, perhaps your apache, is already running on that port. Use netstat to determine what service is using that port. Will need to see you conf file to determine further issues. Also, what OS enviro are you running this in? MacOs? Could be permissions issues somewhere..

Comment: @j hoon seo you cable to solve it?